# How to get regex into textbox to only allow numbers (up to 4 digits) to 2 decimal places?

Tags: jquery, regex

This is the fiddle that I tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ry64u/7/

SCRIPT

```
$(".controlButton").click(function() {

       var SHPname = $(this).closest('.row').find('.fname').val();
       var textfieldmask =  /^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/;
        /// check full name 
           if (SHPname.length > 0){
                var testname = textfieldmask.test(SHPname);
         alert (testname);
                   if (testname == true ){
                      var tstnm = "ok";
          alert (tstnm);
                   } else {
                      alert ("Enter digits up to 2 decimal places!");
          $('#fname').focus();  
                     return false;
                  }       
                } else {
        alert ("Please enter price");
         $('#fname').focus();  
                     return true;
            }  
      });
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<label class="required" for="name" title="Enter your name"><input type="text" id="fname" class="fname" name="fname" />Price</label>

 <label for="formsubmit" class="nocontent"><a class="controlButton" href="#" class="progress-button"><p id="BTNtxt">Save</p></a>
    </div>
</label>
```

But this doesn't apply the rule I wanted: Please help me to modify this to match this rule below:

**RULE:** to only allow numbers (up to 4 digits) to 2 decimal places

Comment: Change the `*` quantifier to only allow up to 3 more digits: `/^\s*-?[1-9]\d{0,3}(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RULE: to only allow numbers (up to 4 digits) to 2 decimal places

However, your current regex also lays another restriction: the integer part cannot start with a zero.

Thus, you can use

```
/^\s*-?[1-9][0-9]{0,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?\s*$/
            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jB3dC9/2) (here, the first digit in the integer part can be in the range from 1 to 9, and there can be 0 to 3 other digits after it.)

**This expression requires at least 1 digit in the integer part!** (it *does not* allow `-.55`)

Or

```
/^\s*-?(?!0)[0-9]{0,4}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?\s*$/
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jB3dC9/1) (here, the integer part can include 4 digits but the first one cannot be `0` due to the negative lookahead `(?!0)`).

**This expression DOES NOT require at least 1 digit in the integer part!** (it allows `-.55`)

See your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry64u/10/)

Since lookarounds make regex patterns less efficient (it can be seen if you test both the patterns in regex101.com using `PCRE` or `Python` settings), I'd choose the first regex. However, based on your further requirements, you may choose the second pattern.

Comment: Thank you, I take the second one but how to ensure 2 digits min entered?

Comment: Why not just add another regex check: `&& /[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9]/.test(str)`? Or, just add this check to the 2nd regex: [`^(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2})\s*-?(?!0)[0-9]{0,4}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/jB3dC9/3). However, the 2 digits are checked anywhere, in the integer and the decimal part. Is that what you need?

Comment: absolutely this is what I want. Thank you :)